# If the file uploaded then send the file name or else send empty in the PHP

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I don't know I am doing my best or it will get issues in the future.

I have to display the 7 file type on my page and it will be increased in the future.
So I have taken the array and store the label name and according to the label count, I am displaying the file type. So I have 7 labels in the array and I am getting 7 file types.

The below is the code I am using it.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <?php
      $labelname = array('Label 1','Label 2','Label 3','Label 4','Label 5','Label 6','Label 7');
      $labelCount=count($labelname);
        ?>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <?php 
      for ($i=0; $i < $labelCount; $i++) { 
       ?>
       <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 ">
         <div class="documentUploadWrap">
            <label><?php echo $labelname[$i];?></label>

         <div class="upload_doc">
          <input type="hidden" name="docUploadLabel[]" value="<?php echo $labelname[$i];?>">
          <input type="file" name="docUpload[]"  class="fileupload">
          <input type="hidden" name="docUpload[]" value="">

          <div class="uploadInfo">
             <div class="upload_icon"></div>
             <p>Drop your image here, or <span>browse</span></p> 
             <span>Supports: JPEG, PNG, PPT, PPTX, PDF <br />Max Size: 5MB</span>
          </div>
       </div>
         </div>
      </div> 
    <?php } ?>
```

```
function imagerename($image,$foldername,$pdo){
$image1  = $image['name'];
$filename  = basename($image1);
$onlyfile = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file      = mt_rand();// random number 
$newname   = $onlyfile.'_'.$file.'.'.$extension;
 
$location='/images/'.$foldername.'/'.$newname;

if($extension=='png' || $extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') { 
  compressImage($image['tmp_name'],$location,60); 
} 
else{ 
  move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $location); 
}


return  $newname;

}

// Compress image
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

  $info = getimagesize($source);

  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'application/pdf') 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

  imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

}
```

Now, I uploaded the file in the first two file type, and the rest 5 are empty. Then I hit the submit button and I am getting the below error.

1)
[image]

**2) Notice here If I upload 1 or 2 files the second name continues repeating till 7 iterations.**

[image]

Comment: There must be some other PHP code as well, which receives the uploaded files and calls the functions you've shown? Also on what lines do those errors occur? Point them out please, since we can't see your line numbers.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `<input type="hidden" name="docUpload[]" value="">` and why have you give it the same `name` as the file input? I can't help thinking that is only going to cause problems.

Comment: @ADyson, I updated the error line in the question and <input type="hidden"> I used it because i am getting the file name from the database and if the user doesn't want to update the file then the hidden field will send the same file name to the process. I uploaded the  whole code

Comment: An undefined offset means you are accessing an index in the array that does not exist.  I assume you are looping over this array which is of `count()` 7, this means it will run seven times.  I would suggest flipping it.  Run a loop based on the number of files uploaded and within that loop, check the file type.  You could do this with a case switch inside your foereach loop.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic, Yes, You understood my question. So on the process page, i have to use the loop based on the number of the uploaded files. can you share the example if you have.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic, So I have to use like this $total = count(array_filter($_FILES['docUpload']['name'])); instated of $total = count($_FILES['docUpload']['size']); correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$filetypes_array = [
  "jpg" => [
    "label" => "Label 1", 
    "name" => "Name 1"
  ],
  "png" => [
    "label" => "Label 2", 
    "name" => "Name 2"
  ],
  "gif" => [
    "label" => "Label 3", 
    "name" => "Name 3"
  ],
  "pdf" => [
    "label" => "Label 4", 
    "name" => "Name 4"
  ]
];

// Build an array of your uploads with your preferred method.

$uploaded_files = [];

// Example
$uploaded_files[] = $_POST["inputname"];
$uploaded_files[] = $_POST["inputname2"];
// etc...

// Or inside a loop
foreach($somearray as $key => $value) {
  $uploaded_files[] = $value;
}

// Then run a loop ONLY as many time as you have uploads.
foreach($uploaded_files as $key => $value) {
  switch ($value) {
    case "pdf":
      // do your thing here
      $filetypes_array[$value].label; // Then do something with it
      $filetypes_array[$value].name; // Then do something with it
      break;
    case "jpg": 
      // do your thing here
      // You can access your prepeared array
      $filetypes_array[$value].label; 
      break;
    case "png":
      // another case
      break;
    case "gif":
      // another case
      break;
  }
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code This is only pseudo code.  Basically you want your loop to run only as many times as is needed so that you do not try to access values that do not exist.

Comment: Using $total = count(array_filter($_FILES['docUpload']['name'])) I am getting the total number of file uploaded. but alos getting the error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump()` that array?  Potentially happening because you are running the filter on an undefined index

Comment: I don't think you need to count your $_FILES, I would create an array of the uploads you do have.  Grab the uploads specifically, maybe name each of them uniquely so theres no issues with naming.  Check if they are empty, if not push them into an array, then iterate over it.

Comment: I tried var_dump and I got int(3) and 3 is correct .I uploaded 7 firles

Comment: I am not using the switch because the user can upload more file link png, pdf, Doc,

Comment: What is it you are trying to do once you have the files?  Also what if you var_dump() `$_FILES` The array itself not the count.

Comment: once I get the file then I am sending to rename the file and store the image name in the database or file in the folder

Comment: You can try looping of the $_FILES inside a foreach, like `foreach ($_FILES["docUpload"]["name"] as $key => $value) { ... }` then you could access it like: `$tmp_name = $_FILES["docUpload"]["temp_name"][$key];`. Or print out what is inside it so you can see what you are working with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233581/discussion-between-user9437856-and-vladimir-mujakovic).

Comment: I think my issue not solved 100%. I mean I am getting new issues , According to 7 file types if I upload in 3 and 5 file types then I have to store the details for 3 and 5 but in my scenario it's updating from first one

Comment: I think there is still loop issue.. can you upload your example here?